# Swifty JSON Response Parsing

Tags: json, swift, swifty-json

I am using SwiftyJson. I am getting a response from printing.

```
{ "coin" : 120 }
```

I want to store this response in a variable. How can I store this value in a variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the specific value from response, it's related with type of response.

https://grokswift.com/json-swift-4/

For example, if response is JSON Array, Please try this.

```
let val = response[index][key]
```

**otherwise**,

```
let val = response[key1][key2][..]
```

Comment: Thanks for help, I have a dictionary and on printing I get Optional(110) here 110 is coins. So, how can I get 110 and use it in If?

Comment: If you want to remove optionals, unwrap it